# GLimageProcessing EAGLView Class Method

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing

I want to show the `EAGLView` in my `ViewController` with the above code:

```
[((EAGLView*)self.view) drawView];
```

But it crashes with the error as;

```
[UIView drawView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

it works fine in the `ViewControlller` of `GLImageProcessing` Sample project Provided by Apple.

Answer (score 2):

Your viewController's view does not respond to `drawView:` as it is of type `UIView` (which doesn't implement `drawView:`).
To get the same behavior as in Apple's sample code, you have to make sure that your viewControllers view instance if of type `EAGLView`.

Select the view in Interface Builder and set it's custom class to `EAGLView`:

[image]